# My added ringtone disappears when rebooting

Tags: android, addition, ringtone

I add a ring tone from a raw file like this code below, and it works.
Once I added it, I can open Android System Ringtones list and it appears there, so I (or any other app) can use it.
The problem is that if I restart the phone then that entry from the list is gone.
So, is there a way to permanently add a ringtone?
Thanks

I use this code for adding:

```
private void AddRingTone() //I assume that sdcard directory exists and it is empty
{  //We first copy the raw resource to sdcard:
   String sPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AnyPath"; //AnyPath already exists.        
   File newSoundFile = new File(sPath, "MyRingtone");
   Uri mUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()+ "/" + R.raw.myringtone);
   AssetFileDescriptor soundFile;
   try 
   {  soundFile= getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(mUri, "r");
   }catch (FileNotFoundException e)
   {  soundFile=null;   
      MessageBox("Cannot open " + mUri.toString());
   }
   try
   {  byte[] readData = new byte[1024];
      FileInputStream fis = soundFile.createInputStream();
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newSoundFile);
      int i = fis.read(readData);
      while (i != -1)
      { fos.write(readData, 0, i);
        i = fis.read(readData);
      }
      fos.close();
   }catch(IOException io)
   {  MessageBox("RingtoneManager:\n" + io.toString());  
   }


   //Now we add it to the system list:
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "my ring tone");
   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/oog");
   values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, newSoundFile.length());
   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "me");
   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);
   Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
   Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it disappears, is its not stored in the right place!

The official spot where Android keeps tabs on the media files is located in  `/sdcard/media/audio/Ringtones` or `/sdcard/media/audio/notifications`, whichever suits best!

Android knows zero about a directory called `AnyPath` and the media scanner does not pick it up!

Comment: Sorry, still not working :-( I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: Yes, it is working. Sorry, I had to restart the phone but also wait for that long process of "searching media...". I thought it was already in a system area so no need for new searchings were needed.